# where does localhost name get resolved on windows?

Tags: windows, localhost, hosts, hosts-file

clearly localhost name on windows is resolving on same place other than hosts file:

1. line 127.0.0.1 localhost has a # on the beginning so it will be ignored
2. on lines above, it's said that localhost gets resolved within DNS itself

I've set a custom local URL on hosts file (via Laragon) which is working fine on normal situation; however, when I connect my vpn extension on chrome, this & all other defined local names fail to load page:

```
dial tcp: lookup <URL> on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

well, all except localhost. localhost domains get resolved on all situation & I'm thinking this is because localhost is defined on someplace deeper than hosts file; & if that place can be modified, then I can add my domain to it so my domain will work on every situation too.

### so where does localhost get resolved on windows & how can i add custom names in that place?

Comment: i believe its a dns convention

Comment: yeah me too. so question is: can we create a custom DNS convention?